# How to debug ARM from Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gdb, arm

I'm developing on a ARMv5 board and I'm trying to debug a program on it using an intel Mac OS X,

I tried on Linux without any problem (I compiled the binary using gnueabi toolchain), I run a gdbserver on the board and connect to it on the host machine and everything was fine.

But on Mac OS X it seems to be much more tricky, I think I need a cross compiled gdb too for ARM target but I don't want to install all the toolchain.

Since Mac OS supports iOS remote debugging, isn't there a gdb which could work for ARM remote debugging?

And another question: why do we need a cross-compiled debugger for remote debugging? Can't simply the server and the client communicate by the network without being architecture dependent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will require a build of `gdb` not only configured for the correct architecture, but also object file type: remember that MacOSX/Darwin uses MachO object files where as GNU/Linux systems use ELF.

When using `gdbserver`, `gdb` is run on the development host, and reads executables and libraries in order to build a symbol-map corresponding to the target.  It's for this reason that the `gdb` that Apple ships - which is built for Darwin and MachO binaries - doesn't work.

As for why things are as they are, this is an architectural limitation of `gdb`, `binutils` and incidentally `gcc` - all of which can only ever handle one target environment at once.
With remote debugging scenarios, there is often a need minimise link traffic and target memory foot-print. Remember, the comms link is sometimes a low speed serial-line.   For this reason, as much as possible is done on the development host with `gdbserver` transacting very low-level operations.

Building a cross-gdb environment for MacOSX shouldn't pose any particular issues.

Comment: If I install gdb for ARM target, will it handle ELF binaries? Because, on the Mac OS the goal is only to debug an ELF binary on the target machine but this binary would have been compiled on Linux so I have to read ELF symbols on the Mac OS host.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple tools are going to be of little use to you unless you are using the Mach-O object format.  You will need to build your own toolchain.  If you have Macports installed this will be easy as it includes a port of the arm-elf-eabi toolchain.  See http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=eabi